# How to loop various conditions multiple times

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have 2 arrays (`s_left` and `s_right`) a length (`dis`), the arrays in reality are produced from sensor values.

The first situation entails looping the condition (`s_left < dis`) twice and at the same time looping (`s_right < dis`) once. This is because the sensor values are constantly updated.

Is there a method to specify the number of times a individual condition can be looped through?

Below is a snapshot of code I have began with.

```
public class test {
public void test() {

double s_right[] = new double[]{10, 13, 14, 15};
double s_left[] = new double[]{12.6, 14, 18, 18};
double dis = 12.5;


}
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to loop `s_left.length` times, then why are you using a `for` loop? Use a while loop. Also, your question doesn't make much sense, you should clarify more. To do that, assume you have no idea what this post is about and read your question out loud. Then make changes as necessary. You should change your "loop design"

Comment: I need s_left to loop twice and at the same time s_right to loop once

Comment: upon reflection I think the code i have written does not make sence :) is there a way to distinguish two conditions to loop an indipendent amount of times?

Comment: my initial idea which is in the question is to look s_left first, then inside that loop it again and at the same time loop the s_right :(